# What WiFi adapter should I use to create a WiFi network?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-adapter

I would like to create a WiFi access point. I have a dedicated machine running Windows Server 2012 setup for DHCP and firewall. 4 port network card for my local wired network, now I would like to add WiFi to that setup via a WiFi adapter acting as an AP (Access Point).

It needs to be able to handle up to 10 devices with a decent throughput.

What kind of hardware do I need? I'd ideally like to have something that is internal to the PC such as a PCI card or an antenna but not a separate device, however if my only option is a separate device then it's fine.

Comment: You need to figure out what your hardware requirements are first, then come to us with those and we'll find the ideal hardware for those requirements.

Comment: `not a separate device`; do you consider USB as a separate device? If so, what computer (specifically, motherboard, if it's custombuilt) do you have (the answer I give will vary depending on this)?

Comment: @cybermonkey ASRock G31M-S http://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/g31m-s/ running Q8400 4GB RAM 30GB SSD + 6TB Storage, yes USB device would be fine. I just didn't like the idea of having a router completely separate however i would resort to that if my only option.